# warning: passing argument 1 of ‘uart1_sendchar’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, linux

i am getting warning but i tried to get info from similar posts but didn't get satisfied result 
printstring get unsigned char and send char take *char so do i have to type cast or something ?? please help

```
uartcustom.c: In function ‘uart1_printString’:
uartcustom.c:162:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘uart1_sendchar’ makes pointer
                             from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
uart1_sendchar(string[local_counter]); // print each character
     ^
```

Two functions which are used  are 
uart1_sendchar
and uart1_printstring

```
/*****************************************************************************   
 //     Uart 1 send char                         */ 
 /***************************************************************************/
void uart1_sendchar(char* tempchar)
{
    int temp;
    temp=write(device_uart1,&tempchar,1);
    if(temp < 0) 
    {
        printf("port failed to write\n");
    }
}



/*****************************************************************************   
//      Uart 1 printstring                       */ 
/*****************************************************************************/

void uart1_printString( unsigned char *string)
{
    int local_counter = 0;
    // loop through until reach string's zero terminator
    while (string[local_counter] != 0)
    {
        uart1_sendchar(string[local_counter]); // print each character
        local_counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` is `unsigned char *` so `string[local_counter]` is `unsigned char`

You probably want:

```
uart1_sendchar(&string[local_counter]);
```

Comment: May want to mention that `write(device_uart1,&tempchar,1);` looks wrong too if your proposed solution is adopted. Alternatively the OP may have meant to declare `uart1_sendchar` to take a parameter `char tempchar`. In which case the call of that function and that `write` would then be correct.